# Switch control and caps lock from command line

Tags: keyboard, caps-lock

My tribe like to switch their control and caps lock keys. I know [how to do this](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3697)† from the GUI. I'd like to go one step further, and put this step in my nascent [dotfiles/osx](https://github.com/claybridges/dotfiles/blob/master/osx) file. Does anyone know how to do this from the command line, say using the `defaults` command?

† If you have more than one keyboard (e.g. you use an external keyboard with your notebook), you must remap each keyboard, while they are attached, using the dropdown on the preferences dialog.

Comment: I see that this changes the file `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist` (where `*` is actually a UUID which I expect identifies the host). Inside this file, an array named `com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.*` is modified, where this `*` identifies the keyboard. How to alter this in a predictable way from the command line, I don't know. But at least, it is a starting point.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/benjifs/054e00deee252b5bb1b88e7afe590794 provides a full example.